# Get realtime code execution update with bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, real-time

In general, we see programs running and showing from how long it running in realtime

example
`[#] Scanning is running from 1min 30sec`

The value will keep change dynamically untill the script complete.

How can we do it in bash !

Answer (score 1):

By using printf with a carriage return but no newline

```sh
count=0
SECONDS=0
while ((count < 10)); do
    # computation code goes here
    # just use a sleep for demonstration
    sleep 1

    printf "\rRunning for %d seconds" $SECONDS
    ((count++))
done
echo # just to add a newline in the output
```

SECONDS is a [special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS) in bash

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But its not working actually. 
Suppose i want to see how much time it taking to complete this command below, it should count the duration in realtime

`assetfinder --subs-only plex.tv &>/dev/null`
You can get the tool from here `go get -u github.com/tomnomnom/assetfinder`

Comment: Oh, so you want a timer running while the external command is in progress. That would be easier to implement in a language where it's easier to use threads, or an event-oriented language like Tcl.